# Modifying an Object Using Its Name in a String

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I need an efficient way to convert the column names of a number of data frames to lowercase.

Suppose we have:

```
df1 <- data.frame(VAR1=c(1,2), VAR2=c("a", "b"))
df2 <- data.frame(VAR1=c(TRUE,FALSE), VAR2=c("foo", "bar"))
```

A simple way to get what I want is:

```
names(df1) <- tolower(names(df1))
names(df2) <- tolower(names(df2))
```

A little tedious if you have a large number of data frames, though.
I need something better.

I thought I could use get() in a loop:

```
my.files <- ls()
for(i in 1:2) names(get(my.files[i])) <- tolower(names(get(my.files[i])))
```

but it doesn't work.  I couldn't find a solution using lapply() either.
Any suggestion to modify the column names of a large number of data frames without too much coding?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that uses `setNames`, which is a nice function for modifying the "names" attribute of an object without having to temporarily create a copy.

```
for(i in ls(pattern = "df")) assign(i, setNames(get(i), tolower(names(get(i)))))
df1
#   var1 var2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
df2
#    var1 var2
# 1  TRUE  foo
# 2 FALSE  bar
```

Generally doing this kind of `get` and `assign` routine is discouraged. It's better to just put your data.frames in a list rather than a bunch of named objects in the .GlobalEnv. In your case, you could do something like the following:

```
a <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
a
# $df1
#   VAR1 VAR2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 
# $df2
#    VAR1 VAR2
# 1  TRUE  foo
# 2 FALSE  bar

lapply(a, function(x) setNames(x, tolower(names(x))))
# $df1
#   var1 var2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 
# $df2
#    var1 var2
# 1  TRUE  foo
# 2 FALSE  bar
```